# How to move image onHoverListener in android

Tags: android

I am currently working on galaxy s4 app, in which i want moving image with moving finger, but how to implement this onHoverListener. Please Help. 
And thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use drag and drop http://androidrox.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/android-sample-app-drag-and-drop-image-using-touch/

Answer (score 1):

you can implementing **onTouchListener()** to your imageView like below:

```
img = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_arrow));

img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                int rawX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                int rawY = (int) motionEvent.getY();
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(rawX, rawY, 0, 0);
                    anim.setDuration(500L);
                    img.startAnimation(anim);
                }
                return true;
            }
});
```

Here we are applying **TranslationAnimation** to our imageView **img**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hoverListener implement touch listener on ur image and also implement touchevent in ur activity. then u can use OnTouchEvent's actionMove.

when user doing actionMove find the coordinates using motionEvent object and translate ur view to those coordinates using translate animation.this will give look as if u r moving the image.

Comment: giving same coordinates of imageView in MotionEvent.Move will result in flikering of image......showing 2 images at a time, i.e. not smooth movement of image along with finger.